# Trigger que calcula o valor de revenda do produto não surte efeito esperado em tabela

Tags: mysql, trigger

Criei uma trigger no MySQL que calcula o preço de uma peça de roupa com o cálculo de 50% de lucro encima do valor de compra do produto. **Só que não aparece nada no lugar onde eu queria que acontecesse o cálculo**.

- Na tabela `itens_compra_fornecedor` o produto é cadastrado e no campo `valor_compra` é o valor de compra do produto pelo fornecedor.
- Já a tabela `produto` recebe a chave da tabela `itens_compra_fornecedor` onde a coluna `valor_revenda` deve fazer o cálculo de revenda do produto cadastrado na tabela `itens_compra_fornecedor`.

**Eu queria fazer esse cálculo de revenda toda vez que um produto é inserido ou quando o valor de compra da tabela `itens_compra_fornecedor` fosse atualizado**. Existe como fazer isso ao mesmo tempo em uma trigger ou preciso fazer isso em trigger separada?

### As tabelas são

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
-- A trigger é essa (ela tem que ser disparada quando houver uma inserção ou atualização do valor_compra do produto)
DELIMITER $
CREATE TRIGGER itens_compra_fornecedor_AFTER_INSERT
AFTER INSERT ON itens_compra_fornecedor
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- Cálcula o valor de revenda do produto na coluna valor_revenda da tabela produto
    UPDATE produto SET valor_revenda = ((NEW.valor_compra * 0.50) + NEW.valor_compra) 
    WHERE cd_produto = NEW.cd_itens_compra_fornecedor;
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: "Produto" tem uma coluna cd_itens_compra_fornecedor não seria este o campo para o "join" ?

Comment: @Motta a trigger é criada, mais não dispara.

Comment: ```WHERE cd_produto = NEW.cd_produto;``` resolveria?

Comment: Tem cd_produto na tabela itens_compra_fornecedor !?